# Mini Max Sum with C#

Tags: c#

Im trying the minimaxsum hackerank challenge with c# and keep getting error when I run my code. Currently I cant see where my mistake is and would understand why my code in particular has failed. Assistance will be appreciated. Thank you

Here is my current code...

```
        // Sort the array
        Array.Sort(arr);
        
        // Calculate the sum of all elements
        long totalSum = arr.Sum(x => (long)x);
        
        // Calculate the minimum sum by excluding the largest element
        long minSum = totalSum - arr[arr.Length - 1];
        
        // Calculate the maximum sum by excluding the smallest element
        long maxSum = totalSum - arr[0];
        
        // Print the minimum and maximum sums
        Console.WriteLine($"{minSum} {maxSum}");
```

...and below is error as received from hackerank compiler

```
Solution.cs(28,20): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Array' 

Solution.cs(34,42): error CS1061: 'List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'List<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Solution.cs(50,25): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

Comment: Those compiler error messages are self-explanatory. Please be more specific about what you're having problems with.

Comment: A generic list an an array are conceptually similar, but are still very different things.  It sounds like `arr` is a `List<int>` and you wanted it to be an `int[]` instead.  (Or perhaps you do want it to be a `List<int>`, in which case consuming code would need to use that instead of expecting an `int[]`.)

Comment: A `List<T>` isn't an `Array`. You can't use `Array.Sort` on a list, nor call `.Length`. Both List itself and the LINQ methods you tried to use have their own way of sorting and counting

Comment: The relevant part of the code where you declare `arr` is missing. But according to the error messages you didn't declare an array but a `List<int>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the errors listed in the compiler, it states that the variable `arr` is a List of ints, rather than an array. This changes what extensions it has available to it, and what methods you can pass it into.

To fix it, either you can change `arr` to an array, or you can use methods available to a List as shown below:

Change `Array.Sort(arr)` to `arr.Sort()`,

Then change

```
long minSum = totalSum - arr[arr.Length - 1];
```

to

```
long minSum = totalSum - arr[arr.Count - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

As they have mentioned above, you are currently using a generic list and you cannot use "Array.Sort()" for generic lists. A simple solution will be to use the Lists sorting method instead of the "Array.Sort()", for example :

`arr.Sort()`

And since you are using generic lists, if you want to get the 'length' you would have to do :

```
arr.Count //Returns the actual size of the list/number of elements inside.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your "Array" is actually a `List<int>`

```
List<int> arr = [ 6, 3, 1, 7, 4 ];
var sum = arr.Sum(x => (long)x);
var min = arr.Min();
var max = arr.Max();

var minSum = sum - min;
var maxSum = sum - max;
```

The `Min` / `Max` / `Sum` Methods are available on sequences containing numerical values.

**Note**
Common sorting algorithms have an average time complexity of O(n log n) or O(n^2) in worst-case scenarios, it's generally more efficient to directly find the minimum and maximum values.

Comment: From my observation, Your code will return minimum and maximum values in the array.

My request however was to get minimum and maximum sum of values in the array. 

Kindly reffer to the below which works fine now

https://gist.github.com/apelisam/73473138015be68a64bdcda06301dd13

Comment: @samwelapeli I updated my answer, I misunderstood your question. What I wanted to show is that you must not sort the List. (sorting is expensive)

Comment: Noted with Thanks. Code ran successfully. However Kindly note that upon submitting not all test cases passed with above  changes. I thought it was due to integer overflow and changed the variables to type long to accommodate larger values but still not all test cases worked out.

Comment: @samwelapeli Yes you are correct, if you deal with large numbers or lots of them you need to cast values to `long` while summing them up otherwise this can result in an overflow.